# what is equivalent of linearlayout with gridlayoutmanager (android) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I try to create horizontal listview with 2 row and many column (may horizontal scrollview) like above image. if in android I can use listview with gridlayoutmanager. how to I do in flutter?

and I want to my menu can reorderable, so I use `ReorderableList`,  this my fullcode

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide ReorderableList;
import 'package:flutter_app2/home.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reorderable_list/flutter_reorderable_list.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class ItemData {
  ItemData(this.title, this.key);

  final String title;

  // Each item in reorderable list needs stable and unique key
  final Key key;
}

enum DraggingMode {
  iOS,
  Android,
}

class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  Item({
    required this.data,
    required this.isFirst,
    required this.isLast,
    required this.draggingMode,
  });

  final ItemData data;
  final bool isFirst;
  final bool isLast;
  final DraggingMode draggingMode;

  Widget _buildChild(BuildContext context, ReorderableItemState state) {
    BoxDecoration decoration;

    if (state == ReorderableItemState.dragProxy ||
        state == ReorderableItemState.dragProxyFinished) {
      // slightly transparent background white dragging (just like on iOS)
      decoration = BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xD0E81818));
    } else {
      bool placeholder = state == ReorderableItemState.placeholder;
      decoration = BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
              top: isFirst && !placeholder
                  ? Divider.createBorderSide(context) //
                  : BorderSide.none,
              bottom: isLast && placeholder
                  ? BorderSide.none //
                  : Divider.createBorderSide(context)),
          color: placeholder ? null : Colors.blue);
    }

    // For iOS dragging mode, there will be drag handle on the right that triggers
    // reordering; For android mode it will be just an empty container
    Widget dragHandle = draggingMode == DraggingMode.iOS
        ? ReorderableListener(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 18.0, left: 18.0),
        color: Color(0x08000000),
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(Icons.reorder, color: Color(0xFF6AA848)),
        ),
      ),
    )
        : Container();

    Widget content = Container(
      decoration: decoration,
      child: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          bottom: false,
          child: Opacity(
            // hide content for placeholder
            opacity: state == ReorderableItemState.placeholder ? 0.0 : 1.0,
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14.0, horizontal: 14.0),
                        child: Text(data.title,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
                      )),
                  // Triggers the reordering
                  dragHandle,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );

    // For android dragging mode, wrap the entire content in DelayedReorderableListener
    if (draggingMode == DraggingMode.Android) {
      content = DelayedReorderableListener(
        child: content,
      );
    }

    return content;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableItem(
        key: data.key, //
        childBuilder: _buildChild);
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late List<ItemData> _items;
  _MyHomePageState() {
    _items = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
      String label = "List item $i";
      if (i == 5) {
        label += ". This item has a long label and will be wrapped.";
      }
      _items.add(ItemData(label, ValueKey(i)));
    }
  }

  // Returns index of item with given key
  int _indexOfKey(Key key) {
    return _items.indexWhere((ItemData d) => d.key == key);
  }

  bool _reorderCallback(Key item, Key newPosition) {
    int draggingIndex = _indexOfKey(item);
    int newPositionIndex = _indexOfKey(newPosition);

    final draggedItem = _items[draggingIndex];
    setState(() {
      debugPrint("Reordering $item -> $newPosition");
      _items.removeAt(draggingIndex);
      _items.insert(newPositionIndex, draggedItem);
    });
    return true;
  }

  void _reorderDone(Key item) {
    final draggedItem = _items[_indexOfKey(item)];
    debugPrint("Reordering finished for ${draggedItem.title}}");
  }

  DraggingMode _draggingMode = DraggingMode.iOS;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),

      body: ReorderableList(

        onReorder: this._reorderCallback,
        onReorderDone: this._reorderDone,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          // cacheExtent: 3000,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverPadding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
                sliver: SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Item(
                        data: _items[index],
                        // first and last attributes affect border drawn during dragging
                        isFirst: index == 0,
                        isLast: index == _items.length - 1,
                        draggingMode: _draggingMode,
                      );
                    },
                    childCount: _items.length,
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this my current view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what about using [reorderables](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables), ReorderableWrap:

```
class _NestedWrapExampleState extends State<NestedWrapExample> {
//  List<Widget> _tiles;
  Color _color;
  Color _colorBrighter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _color = widget.color ?? Colors.primaries[widget.depth % Colors.primaries.length];
    _colorBrighter = Color.lerp(_color, Colors.white, 0.6);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
      setState(() {
        widget._tiles.insert(newIndex, widget._tiles.removeAt(oldIndex));
      });
    }

    var wrap = ReorderableWrap(
      spacing: 8.0,
      runSpacing: 4.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      children: widget._tiles,
      onReorder: _onReorder
    );

    var buttonBar = Container(
      color: _colorBrighter,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 42,
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                widget._tiles.add(
                  Card(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text('${widget.valuePrefix}${widget._tiles.length}', textScaleFactor: 3 / math.sqrt(widget.depth + 1)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all((24.0 / math.sqrt(widget.depth + 1)).roundToDouble()),
                    ),
                    color: _colorBrighter,
                    elevation: 3,
                  )
                );
              });
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 42,
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
            color: Colors.teal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                widget._tiles.removeAt(0);
              });
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 42,
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_to_photos),
            color: Colors.pink,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                widget._tiles.add(NestedWrapExample(depth: widget.depth + 1, valuePrefix: '${widget.valuePrefix}${widget._tiles.length}.',));
              });
            },
          ),
          Text('Level ${widget.depth} / ${widget.valuePrefix}'),
        ],
      )
    );

    var column = Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        buttonBar,
        wrap,
      ]
    );

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(child: column, color: _color,),
    );
  }
}
```